# Getting '\\\\' instead of '\' in regex xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I get the XML from a web service in the format below and I want to clean it up (remove the extra slash from XML defination as well as regex) before working with it.
What do you advise me to do?

```
> "\"<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"utf-8\\\"?>
> <MasterDataPullDTO
> xmlns:xsi=\\\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\\\"
> xmlns:xsd=\\\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\\\">
> <ConfigCode>PlayerEdit~Phone~Format</ConfigCode><IsCorporateConfig>false</IsCorporateConfig><Description>InSite
> Player Data
> Module</Description><ConfigValue>^0[0-8]\\\\d{8}|04\\\\d{2}[\\\\s]\\\\d{3}[\\\\s]\\\\d{3}|0[0-8][\\\\s]\\\\d{4}[\\\\s]\\\\d{4}$</ConfigValue><State>Modified</State></ComponentConfigValueDTO><ComponentConfigValueDTO><ComponentCode>SC15</ComponentCode><ConfigCode>PlayerPin~PinRules~AscendingSequence</ConfigCode><IsCorporateConfig>false</IsCorporateConfig><Description>InSite
> Player Data
> Module</Description><ConfigValue>TRUE</ConfigValue><State>Modified</State></ComponentConfigValueDTO><ComponentConfigValueDTO><ComponentCode>SC15</ComponentCode><ConfigCode>
> /MasterDataPullDTO>\""
```

and the regex expression contains '\\' instead of '\' slash

Thanks,

Comment: How are you viewing that string? My guess is that you're looking at it in the debugger, which escapes strings for you.

Comment: They are escaping sequencing character'`s you don't  need to clean that up. You can look more here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Comment: Yes,I am storing this Xml into a string

Comment: string inputMasterXML = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();